# Did Windows suddenly revert one of my folders to a previous state?

Tags: windows-7, windows-backup

I moved some files over to a folder yesterday on my Windows 7 machine. One was a text file and the others were Matlab codes. Today, I had that text file opened in Notepad++ and I was editing, saving, and running one of the Matlab files. I quit Matlab while in debug mode and to my surprise, at that same moment Notepad gave me the message "This file has been modified outside..." and when I checked the folder to see why this could be, I found that **all** of the files that I moved over had been deleted, and they were not in the Recycle Bin. Furthermore, older files in that folder still remained!

I was able to "save" the text file because the temporary copy had been opened in Notepad++, but the Matlab files were gone since I had just closed it.

Searching my entire computer turned up nothing, so the only thing I can think of to explain what happened is that somehow my system restored that folder to a previous version in which the files that I had moved over yesterday no longer existed. This would be consistent with the last Windows restore point for that folder, which is 11 March 2015. I just can't understand how it could possibly do this *while I have the files open*.

I'm not sure what I should be looking for in the Event Viewer to see what could have gone wrong, either. I do not see any errors or notable events that could've led to this either.

Any ideas about what happened, and how I might avoid this? Furthermore, is there a place where I can view a history of all Windows restore activities?

Comment: Notepad doesn't give a message about files which have changed which is one of the reasons it is a bad editor. I just double checked in Windows 7 and that hasn't changed.

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant Notepad++.

Comment: Explanation about downvote? I am not sure what other details I can provide. My folder literally just spontaneously reverted to a previous state while I was accessing it, and I am quite worried now about whether or not this will happen in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is not a Windows issue, but in fact a critical bug in MATLAB 2014b.

http://de.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1090500

This can be corrected by updating to the latest version of Matlab.